# Prestashop Webservice Updating Carts product 'quantity' PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, prestashop

I've spent many days fighting with the REST API cart update function. It was as hard as hell, but not it almost works. I cannot solve just one prblem with a variable. 
How to enter the quantity of items when updating all the options?

I understand that it is just about a couple of code symbols, but have no idea what to do now.

**Help me please!**

Here is my function below:

```
<?php
session_start();
define('DEBUG', true);
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://mypresta-shop.com/');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'GAN3F82KAA71GZRHJF9QYED7UBTFUVF6');
require_once('/home/t/katja89/shop/public_html/PSWebServiceLibrary.php');
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);


function aCart($T_id, $id_customer, $id_address, $T_action){ //aCart(17, 3, 5, 'edit');

global $webService;

 if ($T_action == 'edit') { //  cart update, item is added, but the quantity does not update

$opt = array('resource' => 'carts');
$opt['id'] = $T_id; // 17
$xml = $webService->get($opt);
$resources = $xml->children()->children()->children();

unset($xml->children()->children()->associations->cart_rows->cart_row);

        foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) { 

// I take the couple $cart_itm["code"] and $cart_itm["qty"], but cannot change 'quantity' of items added from the session :(

$xml->children()->children()->associations->cart_rows->addChild('cart_row')->addChild('id_product', $cart_itm["code"]);

//$xml->children()->children()->associations->cart_rows->addChild('cart_row')->addChild('quantity', $cart_itm["qty"]);
//$xml->children()->children()->associations->cart_rows->cart_row->quantity = $cart_itm["qty"];

       }

$opt = array('resource' => 'carts');
$opt['putXml'] = $xml->asXML();
$opt['id'] = $T_id; // 17
$xml = $webService->edit($opt);

} else if  ($T_action == 'add') { // adding a new cart works

$Tovar = "";

        foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
        {
$Tovar .= "<cart_row>";
$Tovar .= "<id_product>".$cart_itm["code"]."</id_product>";
$Tovar .= "<id_product_attribute>0</id_product_attribute>";
$Tovar .= "<quantity>".$cart_itm["qty"]."</quantity>";
$Tovar .= "</cart_row>";
        }

$Tovar .= "";

//$id_address = "5";
//$id_customer = "3";

$psXML = <<<XML
<prestashop>
<cart>
  <id/>
  <id_address_delivery>{$id_address}</id_address_delivery>
  <id_address_invoice>{$id_address}</id_address_invoice>
  <id_currency>1</id_currency>
  <id_customer>{$id_customer}</id_customer>
  <id_guest>0</id_guest>
  <id_lang>1</id_lang>
  <id_carrier>0</id_carrier>
  <recyclable>0</recyclable>
  <gift>0</gift>
  <gift_message/>
  <associations>
   <cart_rows>
    {$Tovar}
   </cart_rows>
  </associations>
</cart>
</prestashop>
XML;


$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($psXML);
$opt = array( 'resource' => 'carts' );
$opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
$xml = $webService->add( $opt );
}
}
```

I get no particular error. 
In my session, I hold product ID (cart item code - $cart_itm["code"] ) and quantity (cart item quantity $cart_itm["qty"]). When the user changes those variables, I need to change the cart contents. For that, I call the aCart(17, 3, 5, 'edit'); function. It works fine if I add new cart aCart(17, 3, 5, 'add'); But I cannot **edit** cart_rows. In the cart_row quantity $cart_itm["qty"] is connected with id_product as $cart_itm["code"] . I cannot insert $cart_itm["qty"] for particular item into cart_row.

In the code, under the foreach line, you see two options I tried (in grey), neither work. I need to get updated quantity of each item in the cart.

```
$xml->children()->children()->associations->cart_rows->addChild('cart_row')->addChild('id_product', $cart_itm["code"]);
```

it works well, it adds cart_row with item ID. But it shows the quantity as 0. I don't know how to make it show me the real quantity ($cart_itm["qty"]) for id_product ($cart_itm["code"]).

Comment: It will help us a lot if you add a little bit more info, as in: What is your exact problem? What do you want to do? What error do you get? an etc...

Comment: @HristoValkanov Thank you very much for your answer, I edited the top post with new information

Answer (score 0):

Few years later...

You could do something like that:

```
$row = $xml->children()->children()->associations->cart_rows->addChild('cart_row');

$row->addChild('id_product', $cart_itm["code"]);
$row->addChild('quantity', $cart_itm["qtyOrSomething"]);
```